# How to include debug symbols in NASM code for debugging using GDB on Windows?

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb, nasm, mingw32

> How to include debug symbols in NASM code for debugging using GDB on Windows?

Having coded some NASM assembly, I want to debug it using GDB.

I assemble and link using the following commands:

```
nasm -f win32 insertion_sort.asm    
ld insertion_sort.obj
```

However, starting GDB (`gdb a`) yields:

```
Reading symbols from C:\Users\nze\Desktop\asm\sorting\insertion_sort\a.exe...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

In the code below I cannot reference `_array` like:

```
(gdb) x/4xw _array
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
(gdb) x/4xw array
0x1:    Cannot access memory at address 0x1
```

Also, setting breakpoint at `_exit`:

```
(gdb) break exit
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401464
(gdb) run
Starting program: C:\Users\nze\Desktop\asm\sorting\insertion_sort/insertion_sort.exe
[New Thread 5488.0x1c7c]
[New Thread 5488.0xc54]
[Inferior 1 (process 5488) exited with code 01]
```

causes GDB to just run the program to completion when run...

**What is wrong?**

The assembly code is:

```
    BITS 32

    section .data
_array: dd 4, 2, 8, 6, 1
_len:   equ ($ - _array) / 4

    section .text
    global _start
_start: 
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    xor ecx, ecx
_outer:
    inc ecx
    cmp ecx, _len       
    jge _exit
    mov ebx, ecx
    dec ebx
    lea esi, [_array + ecx * 4]
    lea edi, [_array + ebx * 4]
_inner:
    cmp ebx, 0
    jl _outer
    mov eax, [edi]
    cmp eax, [esi]
    jle _outer
    xchg eax, dword [esi]           ; swap [esi] and [edi] 
    mov dword [edi], eax            
    sub esi, 4
    sub edi, 4
    dec ebx
    jmp _inner
_exit:  
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Comment: My `nasm` says: _valid debug formats for 'win32' output format are ('*' denotes default):  * null      Null debug format_. Unless yours says something else, there is not much you can do except make symbols global and use disassembly.

Comment: Would you write example commands?

Comment: Jester, why do I need to make symbols global?

Comment: What's going on here? Why this question has the same code of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38773556/using-gdb-to-debug-assembly-programs-produced-by-nasm-mingw-doesnt-stop-at-brea) from a different user?

Comment: You don't actually need debugging symbols, the ordinary symbols will work fine for assembly debugging. The problem with `x/4xw array` is that you need to type `x/4xw &array` instead for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried include the debug information available for Windows (Codeview 8)?

`$ nasm -gcv8 -f win32 -o insertion_sort.o insertion_sort.asm
$ gcc -m32 -o insertion_sort.exe insertion_sort.o`

Comment: Indeed in NASM only the cv8 format is currently supported for win32 objects. To check the list of supported debug formats you can run 'nasm -f win32 -y'.