# Using GDB to debug assembly programs produced by NASM/MinGW doesn't stop at breakpoints?

Tags: windows, assembly, gdb, mingw, nasm

> Using GDB to debug assembly programs produced by NASM/MinGW doesn't stop at breakpoints?

Assembling and linking the program below produce unexpected results when debugging using GDB.

```
nasm -g -f win32 insertion_sort_static.asm
ld insertion_sort_static.obj -o test
```

Now, when I run GDB and set a breakpoint at `_exit`, the program doesn't break at the specified point. Instead the program terminate.

```
gdb test
(gdb) break exit
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401034
(gdb) run
Starting program: C:\Users\nze\Desktop\asm\sorting\insertion_sort/test
[New Thread 6548.0x2c9c]
[Inferior 1 (process 6548) exited with code 01]
(gdb)
```

On the other hand, if I set `break start`, the program break three instructions below `_start`:

```
(gdb) break start
Breakpoint 2 at 0x401003
(gdb) run
Starting program: C:\Users\nze\Desktop\asm\sorting\insertion_sort/test
[New Thread 4520.0x28e8]
Breakpoint 2, 0x00401003 in start ()
(gdb) disassemble
Dump of assembler code for function start:
   0x00401000 <+0>:     push   %ebp
   0x00401001 <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
=> 0x00401003 <+3>:     xor    %ecx,%ecx
```

What is the cause of these troubles? It is really bothering me, and I can't seem to find a solution.

```
;; insertion_sort(int[] num, int len)

    BITS 32

    section .data
_array: dd 4, 2, 8, 6, 1
_len:   equ ($ - _array) / 4

    section .text
    global _start
_start: 
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    xor ecx, ecx
_outer:
    inc ecx
    cmp ecx, _len       
    jge _exit
    mov ebx, ecx
    dec ebx
    lea esi, [_array + ecx * 4]
    lea edi, [_array + ebx * 4]
_inner:
    cmp ebx, 0
    jl _outer
    mov eax, [edi]
    cmp eax, [esi]
    jle _outer
    xchg eax, dword [esi]           ; swap [esi] and [edi] 
    mov dword [edi], eax            
    sub esi, 4
    sub edi, 4
    dec ebx
    jmp _inner
_exit:
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Comment: gdb printed `Breakpoint 2 at 0x401003` when you did `b start`, so that is where it intended to stop.  Have you checked the symbol addresses with anything else (like a disassembler)?  Other than that, I'll leave this for someone that actually uses Windows to answer.

Comment: If your function has stack frame (the push ebp/mov ebp, esp) the `break start` will stop at the first instruction after the prologue. I believe you can change this behavior and stop at the first instruction of a function by prefixing the function name with `*`. So try `break *start`

Comment: Thank you @MichaelPetch - Can you also give an explanation of the exit-label issue?